# unset leaves empty indexes when deleting elements from array

Tags: php

I have found among many answers in SO that 'unset' removes the element from the array but after running this code I have found quite different results.
Indexes 3 and 4 shouldn't exist but they do.

Can somebody explain this?

```
$offset_arr = array();
array_push($offset_arr, array('11','22','33','11','22','33','11','22','33','33','005'));
array_push($offset_arr, array('11','22','33','11','22','33','11','22','33','33','005'));
array_push($offset_arr, array('11','22','33','11','22','33','11','22','33','33','006'));
array_push($offset_arr, array('11','22','33','11','22','33','11','22','33','33','007'));
array_push($offset_arr, array('11','22','33','11','22','33','11','22','33','33','008'));

$temp_arr = make_offset_array_size_smaller($offset_arr);

echo "\n\nafter running a function array size=".count($temp_arr)."\n\n";
print_r($temp_arr);
print_r($temp_arr[4]); // I don't want this. It should work for [2] not [4]

function make_offset_array_size_smaller($input_arr){
    $result_arr = array();
    $lowest_value = '1000';
    foreach($input_arr as $row_arr) {
        if((int)($lowest_value) > (int)($row_arr[10])) {
            $lowest_value = $row_arr[10];
        }
    }

    $input2_arr = $input_arr;
    foreach($input2_arr as $elementKey => $element) {
        echo "\n --- ".$elementKey." - ".$element[10];
        if((int)($lowest_value) == (int)($element[10])) {
            unset($input2_arr[$elementKey]);
        }

    }
return $input2_arr;
}
```

RESULTS

```
 --- 0 - 005
 --- 1 - 005
 --- 2 - 006
 --- 3 - 007
 --- 4 - 008

after running a function array size=3

Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 22
            [2] => 33
            [3] => 11
            [4] => 22
            [5] => 33
            [6] => 11
            [7] => 22
            [8] => 33
            [9] => 33
            [10] => 006
        )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11
        [1] => 22
        [2] => 33
        [3] => 11
        [4] => 22
        [5] => 33
        [6] => 11
        [7] => 22
        [8] => 33
        [9] => 33
        [10] => 007
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11
        [1] => 22
        [2] => 33
        [3] => 11
        [4] => 22
        [5] => 33
        [6] => 11
        [7] => 22
        [8] => 33
        [9] => 33
        [10] => 008
    )

)
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 22
    [2] => 33
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 22
    [5] => 33
    [6] => 11
    [7] => 22
    [8] => 33
    [9] => 33
    [10] => 008
)
```

Comment: Try `array_values($arr)` to fix indices.

Comment: elclanrs this is the correct answer. Answer it again  but not as a comment and you will get a point.

Comment: array indexes are like db id keys, gaps should not be an issue

Comment: Gaps can be an issue if you have a temporary table where you add a few elements and then subtracts some of them and all this happens in the loop and you don't know how many elements you will add or subtract. In case of the SQL DB you don't treat a table as a temporary one or you use it as such very seldom.